# Why this error is generated only for substraction binary operator?

Tags: java

Why, in my calculator program,

```
System.out.println("Answer is" + x-y);
```

gives a compilation error of bad operand. It only does that for the subtraction binary operator `-` and not for any other binary operators (`+`, `*`, `/`)?

Even though the correct syntax is

```
System.out.println("Answer is"+ (x <binary operator> y));
```

yet the given syntax is also compiled and runs without error generation, for all but substraction binary operator.

Comment: System.out.println("Answer is "+ (x-y));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.println("Answer is" + x-y);`

Will generate a String by adding `x` at the end of `"Answer is"`.
And you can not substract from a String.

If you se `x + y` It will be the same. But adding  the values to the end of the string is a valid operation.

Why `*` and `/` works:
Very simple: they  have priority over `+` and `-`

Like `2 + 3 * 4` will be the same as `2 + ( 3 * 4)`

Comment: So as per this, "System.out.println(x-y+"is your answer" );" , will not give any compilation or runtime error

Comment: @AishwaryaSingh That is correct. Because it goes from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

`"System.out.println("Answer is" + x - y);"` gives a compilation error, because you're trying to subtract `y` from the `String` with value `"Answer is x".

The reason is that the operators are executed from the left to the right and first `x` get appended to `"Answer is"` after which the `-` operator takes place. As subtraction is not a valid operation on `String` literals, and hence an error is risen.

Wrapping the numeric operation with braces `(x - y)`, the expression is given a higher priority and is evaluated before the String concatenation takes place.

Note that when testing with the `/` and `*` operators, the compilation error is not risen, simply because there two operators have higher priority than the `+` operator and will be applied before it.

Answer (score 0):

The plus operator is overloaded for Strings, and you are performing string concatenation and math in the same line.  The only way to be sure that the arithmetic result you want is concatenated as well is to wrap the difference in parentheses.

In this context, operator precedence occurs from left to right, so Java will believe that you're trying to do some operation on a String that isn't supported, as it will concatenate `x` together forming a `String`, then attempt to subtract from that String.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why other operator don't give compilation errors is  operator precedence

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is also done using operator overloading the + Operator .
But there is no overloading done for "-" operator.
Priority wise * and / is evaluated first than + so this may simplify your ambiguity